# Python 3.5 Add border to a window or create window (win32api)

Tags: python, winapi, border

I am trying to find a way to add a border around a window, for example I would like to add a red border around notepad.

```
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Untitled - Notepad")
#win32Gui most likely but win32api for demonstration
win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, commandToChangeBorderhere, bordercolour .....)
```

Above is how I imagine one way if its possible using the win32api, if it is possible I would be grateful if somebody could post the correct syntax.

If that is not possible my next option seems a little rough but I think it would work,

```
rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd) #Get the location and size of handle window 
#create a rectangle in Tkinter at the same location as Rect but slightly bigger so its "around" the handle window
```

As you can probably see I'm a bit stuck and not sure what the best approach for something like this is, Appreciate any help (using Windows 10, cross platform not important but would love to see a cross platform solution if one exists)

Thanks,

Ben.

Comment: There is no `commandToChangeBorderhere`. You won't get far at all without spending some time to learn Win32. Don't expect to solve this problem without a deep knowledge of that. There are no shortcuts. Start with Petzold's book.

Comment: I have learned quite a bit of win32, I can set handles, enumerate children, get text from controls / titles, resize windows , get window sizes etc which are all pretty straight forward and I am just trying to find out if there is something similar to  add a simple border. 

This is a personal project and I am asking if there is a simple solution to it , "Go and read a book, there are no shortcuts" is not helpful.

Comment: If there are no shortcuts, and there aren't, then how would you like us to help you. Tell you that there is a simple solution when one does not exist. You are going to need to create a layered window and lay it over the window you want to enclose in a border. And then move the layered window when the other window moves.